# Problema com ext-zip no Composer

Tags: php, apache, composer

Bom dia, estou precisando instalar a class phpoffice/phpspreadsheet via composer, mas sempre me fala que o ext-zip não está instalada na minha máquina, o grande problema é que já instalei todas as possíveis:
php7.3-zip, php-zip, zip e nada de funcionar.

No phpinfo mostra que está tudo ok, mas, mesmo assim a classe não instala.

Estou tentando fazer a instalação em uma conteiner docker com:
apache2 e php7.3.14 em um debian:10.2-slim

Alguém já passou por isso e tem uma luz de como resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Galera, depois de muita pesquisa em sites gringos, vi algo que era obvio para descobrir o erro, usei o comando "composer show -p" e ele me listou todas as extensões instaladas e para minha surpresa, não tinha a zip e todas estavam com o php7.3.12, uma versão diferente do meu conteiner que é a php7.3.14.
Com isso, na hora percebi que o composer olha o php instalado na minha máquina local (Nem sabia que o PHP vinha instalado no MAC), não no conteiner.

Então minha dúvida mudou, virou de como fazer o composer ignorar minha máquina e olhar o container, por agora vou tentar editar o docker-composer para ele sempre subir os conteiner executando o composer update, não é o ideal mas vai servir até descobrir uma forma de otimizar isso.